# Is Linear Programming as "Powerful" as it was 50 Years Ago?

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, linear-programming, gradient-descent

Based on the plethora of advancements in optimization algorithms and computer technology that has occurred in the past 50 years - **is Linear Programming today as "Powerful" and "Indispensable" as it was in the past?**

Are there still some problems that can *only* be solved using Linear Programming Methods? Do we continue to teach and learn about Linear Programming for only for it's historical importance and basis/introduction to help in understanding modern optimization methods (e.g. "a stepping stone") - or is that in certain types of problems, methods from Linear Programming style display some "attractive theoretical properties" (e.g. convergence), even in the face of modern optimization methods such as Quasi-Newton Methods, Stochastic Gradient Descent and Evolutionary Algorithms?

Can someone please comment on this? **Even today, are there some problems that can be ONLY solved using methods from Linear Programming?**

Thanks!

**Note:** Evolutionary Algorithms do not make any significant claims about their ability to converge

Comment: There were a couple decades of excellent research that went into developing linear programming algorithms (particularly interior point methods) into a powerful and mature technology. Yes, these techniques remain practically useful. For small or medium size problems, they are very fast and very reliable and they find high accuracy solutions. Much recent optimization research that you may be thinking of focuses on very large scale optimization problems where interior point methods are not practical. For small or medium size convex problems, interior point methods reign supreme.

Comment: The interior point revolution began in 1984 (with Karmarkar’s method) and continued for about 20 years. So up until 2005 or so interior point methods for linear programming (and for cone programming) were a hot topic in optimization research.

Comment: For linear problems, Linear Programming makes total sense and this will remain. At best, more general techniques applied to a linear problem might "degenerate by chance" to a linear programming algorithm, but it is more likely that the would waste a lot of time.

Any optimization algorithm works by tentative solutions and estimates where better solutions could be tried. Linear Programming exploits linearity to immediately jump to boundary solutions, while nonlinear methods don't have this option. It is a wrong perception that "old" methods become obsolete.